# Homework/school related questions under the education tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, homework

There are some pretty interesting questions about electronic theory that come from students asking homework questions, or studding for a test, however I am not sure that they fit under the education tag, and I can not find another tag to put them under. What is the solution?

Comment: This is a aside, but we all need to remember to NOT JUST GIVE THE ANSWER TO HOMEWORK PROBLEMS.  The point of homework is to learn from the experience, not to get the particular answer.  Most people get this.  We try to lead the OP thru the process of solving the problem.  Unfortunately it only takes one to spoil it, like this answer http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/64165/4512.  Most of us could see the answer from a few seconds of looking at the schematic, but that's not the point.  Please try to resist looking smart by blurting out the answer.  That spoils it for everyone.

Comment: Yes, studding for a test is why they end up having to ask here.

Answer (score 3):

The [education](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education) tag, as well as the [homework](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) tag, are deprecated because they don't inform about the *topic* of the question, only about their scope. Nobody will look specifically for homework questions, so in that the tag is useless.

If your question can't fit any tag apart from those, well think twice about that question. There **must** be one good tag that fits it. At least you should be able to distinguish things such as analog or digital, batteries or transistors (just examples), filters or ALUs...

Comment: What about the tag [tag:theory]? Approved or disdained?

Comment: @ThePhoton I don't think it's to be deprecated. It actually tells something about the question, namely that it doesn't require to be feasible, just to prove the theoretical concept. From another point of view it should be deprecated: it can't describe a question alone, but it needs other tags. Also, I don't think anyone would make a search on that tag.

Answer (score 2):

I can certainly follow the reasoning about why the tag is deprecated.  At the same time, I believe that the questions will be answered in a way that is pedagogically more useful to the questioner if the homework tag is on them.  "Teach a man to fish...."

Answer (score 2):

I think while the homework tag seems useful in principle, there are two good reasons not to bring it back:

- Most of the time the five tag limit is used up on better tags. I suspect few (if any) people would subscribe to the homework tag: homework tag is useful but not as useful as other tags. And if homework tag wil compete with other tags (the premise of this bullet point) I think we don't want it.
- More tags = more housekeeping = more things to get wrong. I think the limited utility of the homework tag might not justify the extra thinking about the homework tag even if it didn't compete with other, more content-related tags.

I think thinking about who would subscribe to or search for this tag might be a good way of judging its utility. I don't know if they test EEs like the do coders on job interviews, but those and scholastic test preparation might be the only times someone would search for homework tag.

Answer (score 1):

The homework tag used to be here but was listed for quite some time as deprecated. Some months ago I suggested a Wiki tag edit that made it clearer it shouldn't be used for new questions and also untagged some remaining questions.The following post on the SO meta site gives a bit of further background:

[The homework tag is now officially deprecated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated)

But in my opinion the general 'vibe' which I support is that while asking homework questions is perfectly OK they should stand alone as good questions that will benefit others regardless of whether they are students or not. Most homework should (hopefully) be about solving real problems and tagged as you would any other question.

You can always mention within a question it's homework if you think necessary to give a bit of background on your level of experience. Other opinions may vary but  <strike>I think the education tag should be reserved for questions relating to specific EE courses and resources for learning.</strike> I see clabacchio mentioned that is deprecated also and should not be used.

Answer (score 1):

"*Is this a homework question?*" constantly shows up in the comments anyway.

The [homework](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) tag shouldn't be deprecated.  It provides an important bit of meta-information about the question.  That can help provide a good answer.  In combination with the contents of the question, [homework](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) can hint at the following:

- Something about asker's background
- Desired level of idealization.  (Ignore the input offset of the OpAmp, or not.)
- Desired method of solution.  (Microcontroller solution will not work for an analog class.)

That is of course, if everything else is right with the question: not repetitive, not too localized, prior research is demonstrated, asker remains involved, etc.

@clabacchio made an argument that nobody will be searching for the homework tag.  Perhaps, that's correct.  But, somebody might want to *exclude* questions with [homework](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework).  Having an ability like that would make our knowledge system better.